# Could not resolve org.freemarker:freemarker:[2.3.20, 2.4) in Ktor project

Tags: intellij-idea, freemarker, ktor

So I cloned one of my old projects into IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition) & I am getting this error while building:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.freemarker:freemarker:[2.3.20, 2.4).
     Required by:
         project : > io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:1.5.1
      > Failed to list versions for org.freemarker:freemarker.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor/org/freemarker/freemarker/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor/org/freemarker/freemarker/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor/org/freemarker/freemarker/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

**build file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

group 'com.mayurg'
version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-websockets:$ktor_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.122-kotlin-1.4.10"
    testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version"
    implementation 'org.litote.kmongo:kmongo:4.3.0'
    implementation 'org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:4.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14'
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-network-tls:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version"
}
```

**Versions:**

```
ktor_version=1.5.1
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin_version=1.4.21
logback_version=1.2.1
```

I have tried searching for this error a lot but none seem to be related ktor project & others not wworking for me. I tried changing repositories, updating ktor version etc.

Any help on how to resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: https://kotlin.bintray.com/ website is not working.

Comment: JForg has discontinued Bintary.

Comment: Please try to remove `jcenter()` and `maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }` repositories from `build.gradle` file.